# how to disabled ionic slide box swap

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to disable ionic Slide box Swap. i check many solutions this is worked with error.

```
$scope.stop = function() {
             $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
            return false;
        };
```

added this thing to slide box

```
 <ion-slide-box active-slide="stop()">
```

it is working fine but as i click to content of ion slide box it will show me this error

```
 Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'slidestop()' used with directive 'ionSlideBox' is non-assignable!
```

Comment: Any suggestions? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the $ionicView.loaded it's more clean compare to the $timeout

```
var destructor = $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function () {
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
  destructor();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In **active-slide="stop()"**, you can't pass the function as argument,
here you can pass the slide index which you have to active in slidebox.

Read more details from here [Ionic Slidebox](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/).

Add following code in controller to disabled the swipe effect from slidebox

```
$timeout(function(){
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
},300);
```

I have tested in **ionic application**, there is **bug** if don't write your code in  **$timeout** slidebox **doesn't** add the **enableSlide() effect**.